How to handle properly routes with go router in Flutter
I'm using go router on Flutter. I wonder how to handle routes path in app in a clean way.
What i see on youtubes and websites is not that clean i think.
They put routes or do enum of routes but it becomes fastly indigest.
For my part i do:
   class Route {
      final String path;
      final String fullPath;

  const Route({
    required this.path,
    required this.fullPath,
  });
   }

Where path is local path and full path is relativ path.
So when i imbricate like so:
    GoRoute(
      path: AppRoutes.a.path,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
        child: A(),
      ),
      routes: [
      GoRoute(
      path: AppRoutes.b.path,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
        child: B(),
      ),
    );
      ],
    );

a.path = '/a'
a.fullPath = '/a'
b.path : '/b'
b.fullPath = '${a.fullPath}/${b.path}/

And i go on screen b like so:
    context.push(AppRoutes.b.fullPath)

However, i don't like my way.
Do you have suggestion to make it cleanier please ?
Have a nice day
I saw some packages to automaticate routes but i though it is a lot but i'm still thinking that i could use something like this.

You can improve your route handling by using named routes instead of full paths. This will make your code more maintainable and cleaner, especially as your app grows.
First, modify the Route class to include a name field:
class Route {
  final String name; // Unique name for the route
  final String path; // Path used in GoRouter

  const Route({
    required this.name,
    required this.path,
  });
}

Now, update your AppRoutes to define named routes:
class AppRoutes {
  AppRoutes._(); // Private constructor to prevent instantiation

  static const a = Route(name: 'a', path: '/a');
  static const b = Route(name: 'b', path: '/b');
}

Your GoRouter configuration will now look like this:
GoRoute(
  name: AppRoutes.a.name, // Named route for easier navigation
  path: AppRoutes.a.path,
  pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
    child: A(),
  ),
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      name: AppRoutes.b.name, // Named route for nested navigation
      path: AppRoutes.b.path,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
        child: B(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)

Finally, you can navigate to screen B using the route's name with pushNamed method instead of its full path:
context.pushNamed(AppRoutes.b.name);

